# Load web-application into a webview using local paths for images stored in the application

Tags: android, url, webview, local, assets

I want to be able to create an app that uses WebView to request a url 
from an external web application which returns html and css that 
references images that are assets within the actual application. The 
idea is basically to speed up everything so that images never have to 
be downloaded.

Here is a simplified example:

Server HTML:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
  <style> 
     #myImage { background-image: url("file:///android_asset/myImage.jpg"; width: 50px; height: 50px;} 
  </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="myImage"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

So, is there any way to be able to do this? My main goal is to just have the application request all the HTML from a server, but be able to map the image urls to local resources within the application.

Thanks in advance, 
Leon

Comment: tell me the html files come from server or they are local in app. If they come from server how can you use the images in asset folder. Please ask more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to load all HTML from application side? If you bother that this web page will have no access to network - use WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl method.

For embed images into a web page you can use data:URI scheme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Also you can map your application images even if you are page is loaded remotely. You can use WebView.loadUrl("javascript:....") to "send" images data via JavaScript code (also using data:URI scheme).

**EDIT.**

Firstly, at HTML side your example with embedded images will look something like this:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
  <style> 
     #myImage { background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.....'); width: 50px; height: 50px;} 
  </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="myImage"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

When, if you want to store this page at the application side, you can store it somewhere (string resource, asset folder) and when get it.

```
String pageResource = // get it somehow
WebView myWebView;

myWebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl(
    "http://my.site.com",  // The base url
    pageResource,          // page content to load...
    "text/html",           // it's MIME type...
    "UTF-8",               // and encoding
    "http://my.site.com/page.html");
```

Now the WebView has loaded your page. It is loaded from local resources but from WebView point of view it is like it is loaded from the network. It has access to network resources and JavaScript code working here as well (this is the main difference between `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseUrl`).

Comment: i am not sure if i understand what u mean. can you please give a brief example?